# Importing libraries in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

Recently i have downloaded a library for my project.I have extracted it and i was shocked to see that there are no jar files present in it but contains only .java files and .class files.I want to use those files.Can anyone tell how to use those files in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First import that **folder** containing Java source + class file as **Java Project** into your workspace.

(Right click on your Project Explorer -> Import... -> Existing Project..)

OR you can create a Project and add all the source file to that project

Then **Add** this imported project into dependency project list of your project ( Your_Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects )

Comment: Thank you sanbhat.I still have a problem ..do you mean dump the entire folder into an project or only .java and .class files

Comment: You can copy only Java files and eclipse, while building your project will create class files

Answer (score 0):

Create a library project from source from those files, and include the library project as dependency of your other project.